# Can I access VSTS Build Definition Secret Variables (password variables) into shell script file directly without passing arguments?

Tags: shell, azure-devops

Can I access VSTS Build Definition Secret Variables (password type variables) into shell script file directly without passing arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you need to pass VSTS build variables as arguments into shell script file.

- For **inline script**, you can use VSTS build variables (no matter secret variables or non-secret variables) directly by using the format `$(variableName)`.
- For **File path script**, you use the pass VSTS build variables as arguments, so that the variables can be recognized in the shell script file.